# Gstreamer pipeline merging 2 udp sources to rtmp?

Tags: gstreamer

I can't figure out how to merge 2 udp sources (1 for audio and 1 for video), seperately it is pretty easy but no clue how to merge them being a noob, I know I am pretty close

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtpbin name=rtpbin rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_ \
! udpsrc port=6004 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,payload=(int)96,encoding-name=VP8-DRAFT-IETF-01" \
! rtpvp8depay \
! queue \
! mux.  rtpbin.recv_rtp_sink_ \
! udpsrc port=6005 caps="application/x-rtp, media=audio, clock-rate=48000, encoding-name=X-GST-OPUS-DRAFT-SPITTKA-00, payload=111,channels=2" \
! rtpopusdepay \
! queue \
```

... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know exact answer but I would go this way (we can negotiate some solution via comments :)) :

```
gst-launch-1.0 flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink udpsrc port=6004 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,payload=(int)96,encoding-name=VP8-DRAFT-IETF-01" ! rtpvp8depay ! vp8dec ! queue ! x264enc ! mux.  udpsrc port=6005 caps="application/x-rtp, media=audio, clock-rate=48000, encoding-name=X-GST-OPUS-DRAFT-SPITTKA-00, payload=111,channels=2" ! rtpopusdepay ! queue ! opusdec ! voaacenc ! aacparse ! queue ! mux.
```

Why this pipe:

> - there are three parts of pipeline which are later linked together,
>
> 1, first is flvmux linked to rtmpsink, notice there is no ! sign
> between this part and next udpsrc part
>
> 2, udpsrc video part which
> needs to be first decoded from vp8 and then reencoded to h264 as
> flvmux does understand only h264 (I guess no support for vp8, you can
> check this)
>
> 3, udpsrc audio part which is decoded from opus resulting
> in raw pcm audio and then encoded in aac as flvmux does not seem to understand raw audio
>
> - after mux this can go to rtpmsink which will stream it to given location (I am not very familiar with this format)

Keep in mind that the order in which the elements appear is just the order of creation, it is not the order of linkage.. however I think that elements must first exist if you want to link them therefore I put flvmux at the beginning to be able to use the mux. name later (which is something like alias).
I create these 3 parts of pipeline and then link them with usage of mux. alias..

Comment: I appreciate the effort but does not work just erroanous error syntax error and I thought the commands  had to be in order and have the sink last?

Comment: no they need not to be in order.. the proper linkage of elements must be in order and it is.. I do not get erroneous error syntax.. however it was not working for me neither so I reworked it, now it should be working (I update the answer)

Comment: It works! I spent 12+ hours frustrated and was ready to give up 
when only one person answered, but thank you so much for fixing it 
with a working sample! .Finally! .Mux ! .Thanks !!!

Comment: @user6238466 I am so happy that it works finally :) wow 12+ hours, thats a lot of time.. it takes time to understand how gst-launch works, but there are maybe 3-4 things that you need to know and then you will be able to make much more complicated pipes than this one :) just remember to use `gst-inspect-1.0 element` to check the capabilities of element (and understand which one is sink and which one is src), etc.. good luck in next gstreamer adventures :)